# Is the theory of $R$-modules a first order theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Is the theory of $R$-modules over a fixed ring $R$ a first order theory?
(If so, can I use the upward Löwenheim–Skolem Theorem to show that there are arbitrary large $R$-modules of a given cardinality?)

Comment: My model theory knowledge sucks, but if you only care for the question in the brackets, then you can consider (for $R$ unital and not the trivial ring) the $R$-modul $R^S$ for any set $S$, which can be arbitrary large.

Comment: To use upward LS you would first need to produce an infinite model. As Severin already indicated, one of the easier ways of doing this already gives you arbitrarily large models right away.

Comment: Adding to the existing comments by Severin and Mark, the point is that module-ness is a very low-complexity property: since the module axioms are equations, we can always form bigger modules by taking products of smaller modules. In such a situation, things like Lowenheim-Skolem are overkill. Where LS shines is when no such simple construction methods exist for the theory in question, e.g. for first-order Peano arithmetic or for $\mathsf{ZFC}$. (The way it does this, of course, is by replacing such a theory into a structurally simpler theory via Skolemization.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory of $R$-modules can be seen as a first-order theory as follows:
The language consists of the constant $0_M$, a unary operation $m_a$ for each $a \in R$, and a binary operation $+$, satisfying the following axioms:

1. $\forall x,y,\, x+y=y+x$
2. $\forall x,\, x+0_M=x$
3. $\forall x,y,z,\, x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$.
4. $\forall x,\, \exists y,\, x+y=0_M$.
5. For each $a \in R$, $m_a0_M=0_M$.
6. For each $a,b \in R$, $\forall x,\,m_ax+m_bx=m_{a+b}x$.
7. For each $a,b \in R$, $\forall x,\, m_b(m_ax)=m_{ba}x$.
8. For each $a\in R$, $\forall x,y,\, m_a(x+y)=m_ax+m_ay$.
9. $\forall x,\, m_1x=x$.

Comment: +1, but your $m_a$ became $c_a$. Also, axiom 5 is redundant. If $R$ is unital, we do need the axiom $\forall x, c_1x = x$.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: Oops, thank you for your correction.